# jQuery not reading drop down box text from id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to read the text which is submitted in a drop down box with jQuery, as I then want to post it to php. I've been following a tutorial but I have the issue when it does not read the value from the drop down box.

An alert with the name selected should appear when the refresh button is pressed. (The submit button in the script below is for something different and links to a different js file. Not relevant)

```js
function update() {
  var p1 = $("#playerOne").text();
  alert('youre name is ' + p1);
}
```

```html
<div class="inputForm">
  <form id="frm1" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
    <h3>Update League Table!</h3>
    <section class="playerOne">
      <label for="playerOne">Player One Name:</label>
      <select name="playerOne" id="playerOne">
        <option value="player1">Player 1</option>
        <option value="player2">Player 2</option>
        <option value="player3">Player 3</option>
        <option value="player4">Player 4</option>
      </select>
    </section>
    <section class="submission">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </section>
    <input class="refreshButton" type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="update()">
  </form>
</div>
```

In the jquery file, if I remove `var p1 = $("#playerOne").text();` then the alert will work. With that in the alert does not appear at all.

I have tried having the refresh button at different points in the HTML, didn't work. I have moved where `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>` is within the HTML, didn't work.

I have also tried `.val` instead of `.text`. And `var p1 = $("#playerOne option:selected").text();`. Neither of these worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using simple JavaScript code replace your jQuery with

```
var _val = document.getElementById('playerOne').value;
alert(_val); // it will work for you
```

Comment: I have used this js code in my other js file and it works perfectly. Would I still be able to post to php within the same script by using this?

Comment: Will accept as answer however, just a bit confused as to why jQuery appears to not be working.

Comment: @JacKu sorry. But I don't use JavaScript library so I don't have any idea about jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function update() {
    var p1 = $( "#playerOne option:selected" ).text(); // for getting value in element
    alert ('youre name is ' +p1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body background="mkimage.png">

        <div class="inputForm">
            <form id="frm1" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">    
                <h3>Update League Table!</h3>
                <section class="playerOne">
                    <label for="playerOne">Player One Name:</label>
                    <select name="playerOne" id="playerOne">
                        <option value="player1">Player 1</option>
                        <option value="player2">Player 2</option>
                        <option value="player3">Player 3</option>
                        <option value="player4">Player 4</option>
                    </select>
                </section>
                <section class="submission">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </section>
                <input class="refreshButton" type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="update()">
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is your solution

use val() for getting value for the selected list.

if your using text() jquery .it will give all text in the element.

```
function update() {
    var p1 = $("#playerOne").val(); // for getting value in value attribute
    alert ('youre name is ' +p1);
}

function update() {
    var p1 = $( "#playerOne option:selected" ).text(); // for getting value in element
    alert ('youre name is ' +p1);
}
```

Comment: Still not getting any alert with trying either of these

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to get the selected option:

```
$( "#playerOne option:selected" ).text()
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#playerOne').val() will give you the selected value of the drop down element. Use this to get the selected options text.

```
$('#playerOne option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your selector in your jQuery sentence:

```
function update() {
    var p1 = $("#playerOne option:selected").text();
    alert ('youre name is ' + p1);
}
```